# How to place settings button on title bar wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, modern-ui

I want a settings button like this[image: Modern UI]

But I am unable to place the button. I cant find proper documentation for this.
Code

```
<mui:ModernWindow x:Class="EDiscoveryUI.MainWindow"
        xmlns:mui="http://firstfloorsoftware.com/ModernUI"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EDiscoveryCore;assembly=EDiscoveryCore"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="eDiscovery"  BorderBrush="SkyBlue" BorderThickness="2" Height="999" Width="1071" WindowState="Maximized" x:Name="MainWindows">


        <mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups >
        <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="File" x:Name="FileMenuGroup" >
            <mui:LinkGroup.Links >
                <mui:Link DisplayName="New Project" Source="/NewProjectUC.xaml"  />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Open Recent" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Exit" />
            </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        </mui:LinkGroup>
        <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="View">
            <mui:LinkGroup.Links>

            </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        </mui:LinkGroup>
    </mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
</mui:ModernWindow>
```

Comment: Looks like a MenuItem See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.menuitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, it looks like a menu item but actually not.

Comment: If that is a working UI, install Snoop and inspect it?

Comment: The code not have the settings menu.

Comment: perhaps custom window chrome may help you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
 <mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Settings" Source="/Pages/Settings.xaml" />
        <mui:Link DisplayName="Help" Source="http://mui.codeplex.com" />
    </mui:ModernWindow.TitleLinks>
```

Regards,

Comment: if you need more info on MUI, you can download the source code and search here: https://mui.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: OP requested a button, not a text link.

Comment: No he hasn't. He want a Settings button as it is in the image. To do that is with a "mui:link".